# google-app-engine-django: authentication without Google accounts?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, authentication

[google-app-engine-django/](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/) claims to have an "App Engine compatible implementation of the Django authentication framework".  Does this authentication work only with Google Accounts?  Is it possible to register a user with a username/password and authenticate him/her with that username/password without that user having a Google account?

I would appreciate any pointers to how this could be done with google-app-engine-django without Google Accounts authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Account authentication is simply an API provided by App Engine - there's nothing forcing you to use it. As a result, all of Django's facilities except its models (which rely on a relational DB) are available in the helper. However, as far as I'm aware, the helper is deprecated and no longer supported. More recent is [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/), but even that is deprecated in favor of the new [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel).

Comment: Nick - Thanks very much for your very informative response.  After seeing the helper deprecated into app-engine-patch, deprecated again in favor of django-nonrel, I got cold feet about Django on GAE, as much as I like Django.

I am warming up to GAE's own webapp framework; however, that still leaves the non-Google user registration/authentication/session issue  open for me.  Would you recommend tipfy as a framework for this?  Alternatively, is there a standalone package that can handle this?  If not, would it be possible to use relevant parts of the tipfy framework with webapp?

Comment: I haven't used tipfy, so I can't really recommend it. For your immediate needs, there's my own package, aeoid (http://github.com/arachnid/aeoid) - or, you can wait a bit, as openid and oauth support are on the roadmap.

Comment: Nick - Once again, thanks for your answer.  My target audience is pretty non-geek, so OpenID and OAuth are not ideal.  I asked another question on stackoverflow to explore this a bit more.  In short, the use case I have in mind is (1) user registers with e-mail and password (2) user can authenticate with those credentials and the application can maintain a session for the user.  So, in short, what I am looking for is a package that allows basic authentication and sessions. I'm surprised GAE does not support this common pattern, but I suspect it has to do with security issues.

Comment: OpenID doesn't need to be hard for users - check out things like ClickPass, which allow users to simply click on a service they already have. There's certainly no security reason not to have a session library - but there are plenty of third-party ones, such as Django's, already.

Answer (score 2):

The helper only works with google accounts out of the box.  They did not fully implement the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object, they only implemented what they needed to link it to a google account.

If you want to use the helper, you need to make some changes to the `User` implementation to fully implement the interface and you'll probably need to modify the middleware for authentication, etc, and change the `appengine_django.auth.models.User` object so the `user = db.UserProperty` is no longer required.

Comment: dar - Thanks for the answer.  The solution you are suggesting sounds like it is out of my reach.  Do you know if anyone has done what you are suggesting?